# Составить рекуррентную формулу на Си (от n=0, это важно)

Tags: c, формулы

Есть вот такая формула, надо сравнить левую часть и правую с использованием  такого ряда.
В задании сказано посчитать правую часть, то бишь формулу суммы, c использованием рекуррентной формулы. Помогите написать часть кода на Си, где будет считать эту сумму с циклом DO WHILE и рекуррентной формулой! Нельзя использовать `pow`, надо использовать отдельную переменную для суммирования. Я такое сделал с функцией, но сказали, что надо рекуррентную формулу, а вывести ее у меня не выходит.

```
  s = 0; xn = x; n = 0;
  do {
    an = (factorial(2 * n) * xn) / (factorial(n)*factorial(n) * (n + 1));
    s += an;
    n++; xn *= x;
  } while (fabs(an) > eps && n <= lim);
```

---

```
int factorial(int n) {
  return (n < 2) ? 1 : n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

[image: Формула]

Comment: А 29 — это номер варианта из методички? Стыдитесь, учить нужно было на парах.

Comment: @VladD, Злой Vlad, перелогиньтесь.

Comment: @VladD я хорошо все учу, но сделать все равно не выходит,
учитывая что начинаем с n = 0

Comment: @KirillChukhlib: Вам не рассказывали о рекуррентных соотношениях? Поделите a_n на a_(n-1), посмотрите, чему оно равно, подумайте, как это можно применить.

Comment: Рекуррентный значит `f(n) = g(f(n-1))` т.е. расчёт следующего члена ряда из предыдущего

Comment: @VladD это понял) я могу написать формулу когда факториал один, а поскольку их 2 и они разные то одной переменной не отделаться, так же не выходит учесть при n=1 или 0, ибо тогда n*(n-1) будет равно 0, а делить на 0 нельзя, и не знаю как все это учесть

Comment: @vp_arth это понимаю,  но не могу сообразить как это собрать в кучу, написал в предыдущем коменте.

Comment: @KirillChukhlib: А вы пишите формулу для n начиная от 1. Там делить будет можно.

Comment: @VladD за условием нужно от n=0

Comment: `f(0) = x`, `f(1) =x*x`, `f(n)=k*x*f(n-1)` - ваша задача, выразить k через n. Суммировать будете потом.

Comment: @KirillChukhlib: Ну и что? А делить-то не обязательно для всех n.

Comment: @VladD вот я и пытался сделать проверку что бы не делить, но не вышло это сделать, либо одна проверка перебивает другую, либо еще что то

Comment: @vp_arth это я понимаю, но у меня же есть факториал просто n и факториал 2n, а все это за один раз не выходит посчитать и выразить

Comment: Вам не нужно считать факториалы, там почти всё сократится

Comment: @vp_arth что именно сократится?

Comment: Рекуррентные формулы так и строятся, что первый член последовательности вы вычисляете сами, а последующие выражаете через предыдущие. Поэтому рекурсия начинается с индекса 1. Почитайте внимательно лекции.

Comment: @VladD это тоже понимаю) но я не допер как составить рекуррентность для некоторых элементов. Все равно спасибо что уделили время)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ты уже используешь рекуррентный вариант для x<sup>n+1</sup>, но продолжаешь вычислять факториал рекурсивно - надо от него тоже избавиться.

В формуле есть следующие фрагменты:

```
(2n)!
x^(n+1)
(n!)^2
(n+1)
```

Что с ними произойдёт при увеличении n на 1?

```
(2(n+1))! = (2n+2)! = (2n)! * (2n+1) * (2n+2)
x^((n+1)+1) = x^(n+1) * x
((n+1)!)^2 = (n!*(n+1))^2 = (n!)^2 * (n+1)^2
((n+1)+1) = (n+1) + 1 = (n+1) * (1 + 1/(n+1))
```

Пересчитываем коэффициент для следующего n:

```
*= (2(n-1)+1) * (2(n-1)+2) = (2n-1) * 2n
*= x
/= n^2
/= (1 + 1/n)
```

Получается формула

```
y *= (2*n-1) * 2*n * x / (n*n * (1 + 1/n));
```

Если разделить на n числитель и знаменатель(сократить), получится:

```
y *= 2 * x * (2*n-1) / (n + 1);
```

Ну это если я нигде не ошибся в вычислениях. Если ошибся, то надо подправить :)

> n=0, это важно

Надо просто задать соответствующее начальное значение при n=0:

```
y = x;
```

в последующей формуле оно просто умножится на нужный коэффициент.

Comment: ((n+1)+1) = (n+1) + 1 = (n+1) * (1 + 1/(n+1))
чего с 2 на 3 шаг единица превратилась в это: 1 + 1/n ?)

Comment: Если сократить на n, то в знаменателе останется только `n+1`

Comment: @KirillChukhlib, потому что n на третьем шаге - это n+1 со второго шага

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо большое))

Comment: @Harry, таки имелось в виду `[(n-1)!^2] *= n^2`, хотя...

Comment: @vp_arth Там же написано - коэффициент, вот я и решил, что это уже вычисление той формулы, что строчкой ниже. У меня другой вопрос - с одной стороны да, это рекуррентность - следующий член получается из предыдущего. С другой - явной рекуррентности (вызова функции из себя) при этом в коде не наблюдается (правда, ее несложно ввести явно). Останется ли доволен преподаватель? :)

Comment: рекуррентное соотношение - не совсем то же самое, что рекурсия. Думаю, `an *= k` достаточно. Можно для наглядности в виде функции оформить: `fn(fn_1, n) => fn_1 * k`

Comment: @vp_arth наш преподаватель требует делать все как она хочет, поэтому этого ей вполне достаточно) спасибо за функцию, разберу этот вариант отдельно для себя,  лишним точно не будет!

Answer (score 3):

> Выражение равно Σ f(n), где
>   f(x, n) = (2n)!x<sup>n+1</sup> / (n!)<sup>2</sup>(n+1)

Предыдущий член суммы:

> f(x, n-1) = (2(n-1))! x<sup>n</sup> / ((n-1)!)<sup>2</sup>n

Заметим, что

> (2n)! / (2(n-1))! = 2n(2n-1)
>   x<sup>n+1</sup> / x<sup>n</sup> = x
>   n!<sup>2</sup>/(n-1)!<sup>2</sup> = n<sup>2</sup>
>   (n + 1) / n = 1 + 1/n

Тогда,

> f(x, n) / f(x, n-1) = 2n(2n-1) x / (n<sup>2</sup> (1+1/n))

Или, так как `n(1+1/n) = n+1`

> 2x(2n-1) / (n+1)

Реализация:

```
double kn(int n, double x) {
    return 2*(2*n-1)*x / (n+1);
}

double fn(double fn_1, int n, double x) {
    return fn_1 * kn(n, x);
}


double EPS = 1e-15;

double sum(double x) {
    double current = x;
    double sum = current;

    int n = 0;
    do {
        current = fn(current, ++n, x);
        sum += current;
    } while (fabs(current) > EPS);

    return sum;
}

int main() {
    printf("sum(%f) = %f\n", -0.25, sum(-0.25));
    printf("sum(%f) = %f\n", 0.25, sum(0.25));
}
```