# Вычислить сумму бесконечного ряда с заданой точностью

Tags: математика, любой-язык, ряды

Вычислить сумму бесконечного ряда, используя функции пользователя. Создать два типа программ с использованием внешних (глобальных) переменных и переменных, передаваемых в функцию и из функции.
[image]

x=0,56 Точность=2*(10 в степени -5)

Comment: Вычисляйте, этот-то ресурс при чем?

Comment: что есть "функции пользователя"? какого пользователя?

Comment: Нужно просто вычисление общего члену оформить в виде функции, а вычисления факториала оформить в виде еще одной функции.

Comment: Ну раз все просто, то вы знаете что делать :)

Comment: если бы знал то не писал.Непонятно что делать з точностью как её релизовать в коде?

Comment: с увеличением `i` абсолютные значения членов ряда будут уменьшаться. Надо остановиться, как только эти значения станут меньше заданной точности.

Comment: как это реализовать в коде?

Comment: Вы оператор if знаете? А break?

Comment: Вычислять значения выражения под знаком суммы для последовательных значений `i` (`х` Вам дан) и складывать. На каждой итерации проверять значение выражения под знаком суммы и останавливаться, если оно по модулю меньше, чем `0.00002`.

Comment: В знакопеременном монотонно убывающем ряде отклонение суммы конечного количества членов от суммы бесконечного ряда не превышает абсолютного значения последнего просуммированного члена. Этого достаточно?

Comment: @Harry "Они образованность показать хочут"? Человек же просто спросил: "как это реализовать в коде?"

Comment: Решением в лоб вы задачу не выполните. Мне кажется, тут нужно рекуррентное соотношение искать. Недавно был [аналогичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/743826/176064)

Comment: @Igor Именно так и реализовать - сравнивать абсолютное значение последнего члена с точностью. А по-вашему - человек спрашивает, как в коде два числа сравнивать? :) А вообще - чистый случай домашнего задания без попыток решения. Кстати, будь я преподавателем, то за одно `pow(-1, i + 1)` разворачивал бы такое решение, как у вас... Или за вычисление факториала для каждого члена...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ладно, раз меня тут обвиняют в бессердечии :)

```
int main()
{
    const double eps = 2e-5;
    const double x   = 0.56;
    double fact      = 2;
    double ex        = exp(x+1);
    double term      = x*x*log(1+x)/(fact + ex);
    double sum       = term;

    for(int i = 2; fabs(term) > eps; ++i)
    {
        term *= -x*log(i+x)*(fact + ex)/log(i-1+x);
        sum += term /= (fact *= i+1) + (ex *= 2.718281828);
    }
    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Реализовал, но мне кажется что результат не правильный так как в цыкле выполняется только один шаг. Кто может, проверте все ли норм.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

#define EPS (2 * pow(10, -5))

int fact(int x) {
    return !x || x == 1 ? 1 : fact(x - 1) * x;
}

double getEx(int i, double x) {
    return pow(-1, i + 1) * ((pow(x, i + 1) * log(i + x)) / (fact(i + 1) + pow(M_E, i + x)));
}

double calcSum(double x) {
    int i = 1;
    double ch = getEx(i, x);
    double sum = 0;

    while (fabs(ch) > EPS) {
        sum += ch;
        ch = getEx(++i, x);
    }

    return sum;
}

int main() {
    double x = 0.56;
    double sum = calcSum(x);
    printf("Summa ryada sostavila %.6lf", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: У Вас в `while` - условие остановки, а не продолжения.

Comment: получаю результат 0.020633 если меняю while на fabs(ch) >= EPS то вообще 0.00000

Answer (score 0):

```
double calcSum(double x) {
  int i = 1;
  double ch = pow(-1, i + 1) * ((pow(x, i + 1) * log(i + x)) / (fact(i + 1) + pow(M_E, i + x)));

  double sum = 0;
  while (fabs(ch) > EPS) {
    sum += ch;
    i++;
    ch = pow(-1, i + 1) * ((pow(x, i + 1) * log(i + x)) / (fact(i + 1) + pow(M_E, i + x)));
  }

  return sum;
}
```